# How to insert large amount of data in MySQL DB using JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am using 7 JSON File, and I am trying to insert 95 coloums + 50-100 rows at a time.

This is how my code looks like: I removed some 6 JSON files and other rows&colums. This is a short version of my code

```
<?php
$requestsDone = 2;
$maxRequests = 100;
$currentnumber = 1;
while ($requestsDone <= $maxRequests) {

    $response = file_get_contents("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/".$requestsDone."?api_key=522cexxxxxxxxxxxxx9ax34a");
    if ($response != FALSE) {
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
    }

if (  ($response["title"]) != ""   )
{

        $requestsDone++;

include 'admin/connectdb.php';

try {

    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO TABLE (title,image,money,tag1,tag2) 
    VALUES (:title, :image, :money,:tag1,:tag2)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
    $stmt->bindParam(':image', $image);
    $stmt->bindParam(':money', $money);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tag1', $tag1);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tag1', $tag2);

    // insert a row
    $movie_title = "".$response["title"]."";
if ( $response["image"] != ""        )
    $image = "".$response["image"]."";
if ( $response["money"] != ""        )
    $money = "".$response["money"]."";
if ( ($response["tag"][0]["name"]) != ""        )
    $tag1 = "".$response["tag"][0]["name"]."";
if ( ($response["tag"][1]["name"]) != ""        )
    $tag2 = "".$response["tag"][1]["name"]."";

    $stmt->execute();

    echo "New records created successfully ".$currentnumber++."  <br/>";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $conn = null;

}

}
?>
```

I am getting 2 type of errors: Sometime 1st error, sometime 2nd error.

**1st Error:** [Cloudflare time-out: Error 504 Screenshot](https://image.prntscr.com/image/VwSfU4hfQd6aDvM4a-3cyQ.png)

**2nd Error:** `Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away`

Please let me know, if you need more information.

Edit:

This is how one of the JSON file looks like

```
{"adult":false,"backdrop_path":"/87hTDiay2N2qWyX4Ds7ybXi9h8I.jpg","belongs_to_collection":null,"budget":63000000,"genres":[{"id":18,"name":"Drama"}],"homepage":"http://www.foxmovies.com/movies/fight-club","id":550,"imdb_id":"tt0137523","original_language":"en","original_title":"Fight Club","overview":"A ticking-time-bomb insomniac and a slippery soap salesman channel primal male aggression into a shocking new form of therapy. Their concept catches on, with underground \"fight clubs\" forming in every town, until an eccentric gets in the way and ignites an out-of-control spiral toward oblivion.","popularity":9.765478999999999,"poster_path":"/adw6Lq9FiC9zjYEpOqfq03ituwp.jpg","production_companies":[{"name":"Regency Enterprises","id":508},{"name":"Fox 2000 Pictures","id":711},{"name":"Taurus Film","id":20555},{"name":"Linson Films","id":54050},{"name":"Atman Entertainment","id":54051},{"name":"Knickerbocker Films","id":54052}],"production_countries":[{"iso_3166_1":"DE","name":"Germany"},{"iso_3166_1":"US","name":"United States of America"}],"release_date":"1999-10-15","revenue":100853753,"runtime":139,"spoken_languages":[{"iso_639_1":"en","name":"English"}],"status":"Released","tagline":"How much can you know about yourself if you've never been in a fight?","title":"Fight Club","video":false,"vote_average":8.199999999999999,"vote_count":8047}
```

Comment: I suppose you can't use other serialisation than json ? Can you transform your json on csv for example ? mySQL can add a very large csv file (and it's just text file)

Comment: I don't know stuff about csv. I can use 3 alternatives: ext-curl, pecl/httpv1, pecl/http v2

Comment: which one should i use @Xenofexs

Comment: _Tip:_ This `$image = "".$response["image"]."";` is the same thing as `$image = $response["image"];`

Comment: json is only text. You can't add very large text in MySQL. It's not a good idea. Can you please add this line at your code (after the json_decode) and add the result to your question ? `echo '<pre style="border:1px solid; text-align:left; background:grey; font-size:16px; padding:5px;">'
   , print_r($response, true), '</pre> <hr/>';`

Comment: Done @Xenofexs bro

Comment: I've decoded your json (like you do). Look at this link :  http://codepad.org/vRK6Kp3K . $response is not array but object. Try to change your code like that : `$response['title'];` ====> `$response->title;` . And same for all your call to $response

Comment: Bro, I am using 7 JSON files at a time, and I will use this code like 500k times. So, Almost 3m-4m JSON files. 

So can i change the code using a script, like u did?

Comment: Can you dump the structure MySQL table  ? I see nothing actually. I want try to reproduce your case

Comment: Also, I tried use only 1 JSON file, then also same bug. So OFC it will give me that bug with 7 files. 

Wait 2 min, i will give u

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147182/discussion-between-xenofexs-and-josh).